# C# change label text when button clicked multiple times

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Sorry I am new to this just wondering if someone can help, I am trying to get my label to change its text every time I click the button. Not sure how I should go about it. Can anyone help me please.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        string[] MonthName;
        MonthName = new string[12];

        MonthName[0] = "January";
        MonthName[1] = "February";
        MonthName[2] = "March";
        MonthName[3] = "April";
        MonthName[4] = "May";
        MonthName[5] = "June";
        MonthName[6] = "July";
        MonthName[7] = "August";
        MonthName[8] = "September";
        MonthName[9] = "October";
        MonthName[10] = "November";
        MonthName[11] = "December";


            label1.Text = (MonthName[0]);
            label1.Text = (MonthName[1]);
```

Comment: What research have you done ? is this your home work ?

Comment: Simon Whitehead show the fastest way to implement. But if you want to use static button captions (MonthName), you can declare them in class scope and use then in the button1_Click function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

Declare the array and an int in the class

```
string[] MonthName = { "Jan", "Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec" };
    static int i = 0;
```

Then in the button click

```
protected void btnAddMonth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblMonth.Text = MonthName[i];
    i = (i+1) % 12;
}
```

Comment: you are welcome, but keep in mind the counter is static. If it was helpful could u just mark it?

Comment: And one more thing, nect time when u post a question do a lot of research on it first, cos if u dont do that u might get banned here. So make sure u really cant get a solution by your own n then post. Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

Might be easier to do it this way:

```
DateTime currentDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1); // Per Habib's suggestion

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    label1.Text = currentDate.ToString("MMMM");
    currentDate = currentDate.AddMonths(1);
}
```

Comment: +1 interesting :). IMO, your `currentDate` should be `new DateTime(2013, 1, 1);` so that the month always starts from January.

Answer (score 0):

1. Move the array initialization outside the click handler.
2. Have a hidden label that stores the counter to determine which element in the array to pick.

Something like the below code. Please mind that this is not the most elegant code, but I wanted to keep it simple as you said you are new to this.

```
var Months = new List<string>
            {
                   "January",
                   "February",
                   "March",
                   "April",
                   "May",
                   "July",
                   "August",
                   "September",
                   "October",
                   "November",
                   "December"
            };

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(labelHiddenCounter.Text))
            labelHiddenCounter.Text = "0";

        if(labelHiddenCounter.Text == "11")
            labelHiddenCounter.Text = "-1";

        var nextCounter = Convert.ToInt32(labelHiddenCounter.Text) + 1;

        label1.Text = (Months[nextCounter]);

        labelHiddenCounter.Text = nextCounter.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Why should he create another label if a simple int is enough?

Comment: @Areks: Without a hidden label, how will he remember the current item index across multiple button clicks?

Comment: Using an ordinary integer outside the button click event, for example. Your approach is 'hacky' at best.

Answer (score 0):

If you want random months to appear whenever you click the button use.

```
        var random = new Random();
        var months = new List<string>
        {
             "Jan", 
             "Feb", 
             "Mar", 
             "Apr", 
             "May", 
             "Jun", 
             "Jul", 
             "Aug", 
             "Sep", 
             "Oct", 
             "Nov", 
             "Dec"
        };

        int index = random.Next(months.Count);
        label1.Text = (months[index]);
```